# Hi Stackoverflow Family. Pre 2D Kndly hlp. The relevant error-causing widget was: quiz$. Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

```
? quiz(
            answerquestion: _answerquestion,
            questionindex: _questionindex,
            questions: _questions,
          )
```

quiz Page
I often visit
https://github.com/Ammarbajwa19/quiz_app

Comment: Please add the erroring code to your question so that you can implement a minimal implementation. I can't figure out which part of the current question is an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: when I click the choice of 2nd mcq that error will appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

In the **main.dart** file at line **72**, you are passing the **_answerquestion** parameter to the quiz widget but the quiz widget accepts the string. So you will have to pass **String**, not the **Function**.

Comment: but it gives an error in main.dart(The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.) file and also in quiz.dart file